# Laravel access-control-allow-origin some method work, some method not

Tags: laravel

web client use angularjs to access laravel web api, i use middleware as suggested from google search, code as below:
middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])
            // Depending of your application you can't use '*'
            // Some security CORS concerns 
            //->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '10000')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    }
```

route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'stock','middleware' =>'authapi'],function(){

    Route::post('trendvote',function(){return _index::trendVote(Input::all());});//this one report cors errors

    Route::post('trendindexminute',function(){return _index::getIndexMinute(Input::all());});//this one still works fine

});
```

it worked fine until today it suddenly one method report cors error again h, the strange thing is that: other method which also use the same midddleware works correctly,please help , thanks in advance

Comment: If the function trendVote fails, it may not set the appropriate headers.  Did you try modifying the $request variable before sending it to the $header function?

Answer (score 0):

it is a little shame, the problem is that a interal 500 error can make the cors happen, so the solution is actually fix the bug,then things work fine XD